# Show splash screen or loading indicator until ALL images are ready | Expo | React Native

Tags: android, react-native, image, expo

My images take long time to load, I wanted a way to show some indicator unless all the images are loaded, How can I do that

I am using react native with expo.

I saw that to detect loading progess of image, onLoadEnd() callback is used, but I have plenty of images, and adding that callback to all of them seemed not the best way,
I am hoping if there is some other way to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the docs here

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/

You will have a splash screen that will start appearing when the native app loads and will disappear after all the Javascript is loaded.

Ideally, you want to hide it at your initial navigation screen.

Comment: Does it takes into account that images are downloaded from uris and loaded?

Comment: Just hide the splash screen after all your images have been loaded.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I have plenty of images here and there, do I have to add onLoadEnd to each of them? I was hoping if there is some better way

Comment: You could use `Promise.all` to wait until ALL are loaded and hide the splash screen in the `resolve` callback

Comment: Something like that https://snack.expo.dev/@dittmarconsulting/dbcdce

Comment: Oh, also i think , onLoadStart should add promise.pending to those imagePromise variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240126/discussion-between-ali-and-thomas-dittmar).